# Code First EF6 Not retrieving Class

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

New to EF6. I have several classes that are loading fine but one of them isn't playing nice.

This is the Offending class

```
public class Family
{
    public int FamilyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Standing { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Father { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Mother { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Spouse { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Siblings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

It's parent class

```
public class Ven
{
    public int VenId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Family Family { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Devotion> Devotions { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And one of the others that is working

```
public class Devotion
{
    public int DevotionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

I'm populating them with a seed that used to be really simple but has exploded as I've been trying to figure out what's going on.

```
context.Families.AddOrUpdate(
    f => f.FamilyId,
    new Family
    {
        FamilyId = 1,
        Name = "Tal",
        Standing = "Baron",
        Father = context.Persons.Find(1),
        Mother = context.Persons.Find(2),
        Children = new List<Person> {context.Persons.Find(3)}
    }
);

...
Family = context.Families.Find(1)
...
Devotions = new List<Devotion> { context.Devotions.Find(1), context.Devotions.Find(2) },
```

I've read several SO posts trying to figure this out but can't find anything that helps.

EDIT 1:
Alright, so I've tried some things. I completely deleted the database and restarted it. I'm still having the same issues.

I've verified that the Family is added to table. And by throwing errors I have verified that the Family is being found by ID.

But the Ven Table is still not getting a value in it's Family_FamilyId column even though the family is being assigned to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image: DataBase]

EDIT 2:
[Entire Seed Function](https://pastebin.com/K2TB9ZCh). This used to be just one big "new Ven."

Comment: so what's your problem!?

Comment: EF6 is not retrieving the data for the class as stated in the title.

Comment: which class, which variable, which line?

Comment: The one marked "Offending Class"

Comment: try calling `context.SaveChanges()` before `Family = context.Families.Find(1)`. let me know if it worked.

Comment: It is being called before.

Comment: Do you have expected entity in database?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov It seems to be making a new Family every time it seeds. But with a higher and higher FamilyID. The FamilyID on the Ven Class is sticking on an entry in the table only NULL values.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Setting the FamilyId on it's seed to 16 (The next available ID) seems to caused it to stop creating new entries but adding 

Family = context.Families.Find(16)

To the Ven is not updating the FamilyId on the Ven table.

Comment: @Arven
I've added an edit to question. Does that help clear up what I'm asking?

Comment: @JasonTucker, show us code, where you create `Ven` entity with `Family` assigning.

Comment: @Arvin I've added a Pastebin of the entire Seed method.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I honestly don't know why, but putting the Seed into an initializer and putting the [new Ven] statement back into one giant add made it start working again.